Cannot find module '@spartacus/pdf-invoices/components' or its corresponding type declarations in Composable 6.6
We came to an issue updating to composable 6.6 from 6.5.
Error: node_modules/@spartacus/order/components/order-details/my-account-v2/download-invoices/my-account-v2-download-invoices.component.d.ts:3:39 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@spartacus/pdf-invoices/components' or its corresponding type declarations.
3 import { InvoicesListComponent } from '@spartacus/pdf-invoices/components';
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error: node_modules/@spartacus/order/components/order-details/my-account-v2/download-invoices/my-account-v2-download-invoices.module.d.ts:7:21 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@spartacus/pdf-invoices/components' or its corresponding type declarations.
7 import * as i5 from "@spartacus/pdf-invoices/components";
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Please advise

we found the solution. added this "@spartacus/pdf-invoices" "~6.6.1" in package.json
